Greek names of cities of Persia
I know that some cities and places in Iran and Afghanistan have historical Greek names. Like Persepolis. Where can I find those names and their meanings?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Are you interested in exonyms or endonyms?

Some of them (several called "Alexandria on the ...") can be found on a Wikipedia map of Alexander's empire

Please revise the title to ask a clear question (who, what, where, when). The clearer the question, the more likely you are to get an acceptable answer.  Titles that don't ask clear questions are frequently closed as unclear/lacking focus. more information at history.meta. How to write a good question may also be useful.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)
